# Passing values from php to html function

Tags: php, html, function

I am trying to get the coordinates generated by the geocode passed to the function initialize so that a map with the location can be drawn. I have carried over the variables from the php to the function initialize() but it is not reading the lati and longi values.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

        <?php


    $dlocation =$_POST['address'];
// Get lat and long by address      
        $address = $dlocation; // Google HQ
        $prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);
        $geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=false');
        $output= json_decode($geocode);
        $latitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        $longitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;


echo 'latitute:'.$latitude . "\n";
echo 'Longitude:'. $longitude. "\n";

?>
        <script type="text/javascript">





    function initialize()
{   var lati = "<?php echo $latitude;?>";
    var longi = "<?php echo $longitude;?>"

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(('lati', 'longi'));
var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng('lati', 'longi'),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);

}    

    </script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
        <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 1000px; height: 900px">


        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the resultant HTML ? Can `function initialize()` read the values?

Comment: are you sure that this call is correct: `var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(('lati', 'longi'));` ? I think it should be sth like this : `var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng((lati, longi));`

Answer (score 1):

```
var longi = "<?php echo $longitude;?>"
                                      ^ semi-colon is missing
                                        and it should be number, not string
```

And

```
var latlng = 
new google.maps.LatLng(('lati', 'longi'));
                         ^ you should pass variable value not string
```

And

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng('lati', 'longi'),
                               ^ same as above, variable, not string
```

Comment: semi-colon in your first snippet is not desired I think , its optional

Comment: @sakhunzai, didn't know it is optional. Javascript surely is forgiving programmer for a lot of things.

Comment: though its good to put those shoes on , to avoid some minifier screwing your code. Which puts everything on single line

Answer (score 0):

Change you function to look like this

Give the [API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) reference , google.maps.LatLng class constructor accepts `Number` value

```
function initialize()
   {       
    var lati = parseFloat("<?php echo $latitude;?>");
    var longi= parseFloat("<?php echo $longitude;?>");

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng((lati, longi));
    var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(lati, longi),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);
   }
```

I don't know the correctness of your function w.r.t Google Maps , this is just javascript fix