# 2 php arrays into one 2d javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, mongodb, google-maps-api-3

I have this code:

```
$lat = $obj['geo']['coordinates'][0];
$long = $obj['geo']['coordinates'][1];
```

Its to do with google maps. So these two variables take the coordinate values (lat and long) from a mongodb. Assume this works.

And I have this in the javascript:

```
var loc = <?php echo json_encode($lat, $long); ?>;
```

I'm attempting here to make these two php arrays into a 2d javascript array, but it's not working.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you probably need to use the [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) class, e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18863955/492335

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var loc = <?php echo json_encode(array($lat, $long)); ?>;
```

*If it's not that what you need, just tell it, i have some more ideas ;-)*

Comment: I nearly voted this the right idea... The issue is now is that using the "alert", it's separating lat and long and i need them to be one element. Any ideas?

Comment: So you want to convert lat and long to one single element? And just a little tip, instead of using "alert", use "console.log(...)"

Comment: ok I have used console.log() so now it shows on the console haha. and yes I do :) in order to plot it on the map, see

Comment: i'll show an example: on the console atm it is 50.8816387 test.php:53
-1.8926108 on separate lines. I need them to be on one line effectively